# Blazor same page parameters navigation without scrolling

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I would like to implement modal navigation in Blazor Server-Side app with the following logic:

1. Page always displays documents table
2. Table might have many entries, so user can scroll the page down.
3. User clicks on row to open modal, URL is being updated (easy to share with other users).
4. User closes modal returning to the same position to continue browsing, URL is reset.

So far I cannot achieve the last point with standard **NavigateTo**. Even simple call `navManager.NavigateTo("/Documents", false)` scrolls page to the top.

Is it possible with JS Url manipulations?
Thank you

PS: To implement same user experience I've also been thinking about different edit page instead of modal with returning user to exact row in data table on close. May be, to use pagination in table and return to it.

```
@page "/Documents"
@page "/Documents/{ID:int}"
@inject NavigationManager navManager

...
if (ID > 0)
{
    <DocumentForm OnClose="CloseModal" ID="@ID"></DocumentForm>
}

[Parameter]
public int ID { get; set; }
...
private void SelectDocument(Document doc)
{
   navManager.NavigateTo($"/Documents/{doc.ID}");
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail about step #3?  When the user clicks on a table row a modal is opened.  But what do you mean that URL is being updated?  Usually URL does not change when a modal is opened on a page

Comment: something like this: https://cec-blazor-database.azurewebsites.net/fetchdatamodal.  Will point you to a repo if this is what you want.

Comment: Jason, I use `navManager.NavigateTo($"/Documents/{doc.ID}")` in step3, this updates URL and opens modal.

Comment: MrC, almost, example does not update main URL, i.e. fetchdatamodal/15. User is not able to share it with others. There is useful functionality  at `https://cec-blazor-database.azurewebsites.net/fetchdata`. User can open table page 5, click on Edit, new page opens, user save data and on close gets back to updated table page 5.